# App not showing up as a broadcast service in RPBroadcastActivityViewController

Tags: ios, swift, replaykit

I'm trying to use Replaykit to start a broadcast session (recording the App screen works ok) and it opens up a picker from where broadcasting Apps can be picked, Youtube, Facebook and Periscope show up but not my App, code:

```
if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
  RPBroadcastActivityViewController.load { broadcastAVC, error in
    guard error == nil else {
      print("Cannot load Broadcast Activity View Controller.")
      return
    }
    if let broadcastAVC = broadcastAVC {
      broadcastAVC.delegate = self
      self.viewController.present(broadcastAVC, animated: true, completion: {
        // broadcastactivityviewcontroller will perform the callback when the broadcast starts (or fails)
      })
    }
  }
}
```

Full source code [here](https://github.com/kaelhem/cordova-replay/blob/master/src/ios/CDVCordovaReplay.swift), the code is in the `startBroadcast` function.

I also tried loading using `withPreferredExtension` and it says `preferred broadcast service not found`. When I go to the control centre to try starting a broadcast session I see no `Start Broadcast` button and no Apps, just `Start Recording`, I'm using IOS11 so I tried with a phone using IOS12 and same result concerning control centre.
How can I get my App to show in the picker, thanks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had to add the Broadcast Extension, in Xcode, File -> New -> Target -> Broadcast Upload Extension. This extension was then displayed in the picker.

Answer (score 0):

Another common issue is that the `Deployment Target` for your app (specifically your app, not just your Broadcast Extension) needs to be at least iOS 14.0. If it's any lower, it won't show up even if your device is on the correct version.