# ReplayKit Broadcast upload extension - Service not found

Tags: ios, swift, replaykit

I'm working on an IOS swift application that will allow the user to record the entire screen, any app and even the home screen.

In order to do that, I added a Broadcast Upload Extension to my app.

First I used the `RPSystemBroadcastPickerView` class in order to add a record button to my view that allow the user to open the record popup and select to which app he wants to broadcast the screen flow. And it's working fine :

[image]

But I would like to avoid this step and directly open the popup when the app launch.

So I wrote the following code to do that :

```
RPBroadcastActivityViewController.load(withPreferredExtension: "ch.jroueche.RecordApp.TestScreen", handler:  {broadcastAVC,error in
    guard error == nil else {
        print("Cannot load Broadcast Activity View Controller.")
        return
    }
    
    if let broadcastAVC = broadcastAVC {
        broadcastAVC.delegate = self
        self.present(broadcastAVC, animated: true, completion: {
            // broadcastactivityviewcontroller will perform the callback when the broadcast starts (or fails)
            print("I've START")
            
        })
    }
})
```

Unlike`enter code here` the `RPSystemBroadcastPickerView` solution, I'm getting the following error :

[image]

The preferred broadcast service could not be found.

My issue is similar to the following post :
[App not showing up as a broadcast service in RPBroadcastActivityViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54536382/app-not-showing-up-as-a-broadcast-service-in-rpbroadcastactivityviewcontroller)

I also added the extension and the preferred extension identifier is correct.

Why would it be possible using the `RPSystemBroadcastPickerView` and not programmatically using `RPBroadcastActivityViewController`class. That does not make sense for me.

Does someone have an idea of what could be the issue and how could I fix it ? Or a workaround in order to do this screen record.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you solve it?

Comment: No, I didn't. I temporarily used the workaround to open the RPSystemBroadcastPickerView and simulate a click on it. This solution is working, but is a little bit trash.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that `RPBroadcastActivityViewController` shows ONLY `Broadcast Setup UI Extension`, while `RPSystemBroadcastPickerView` shows ONLY `Broadcast Upload Extension`. But I have no idea why, as both of them are stated to show list of available providers/services.

It would be very helpful if someone could bring more details on the topic.